# Documentation's search algorithm should be more intelligent

Tags: feature-request, documentation

As it is right now, searching for "design patterns" will not even return the "design-patterns" tag. Finding documentation shouldn't require detailed knowledge of SO-specific tags.

Fuzzy searches and aliases (e.g. "DDD" instead of "Domain-Driven Design") could be useful as well.