# Make documentation more searchable

Tags: feature-request, documentation, search

I would like to propose some better ways to search documentation.

Right now if I want to find something in the documentation it's terribly difficult. It's good to make people write good documentation and stop plagiarism and fix rep so on, and I know SO has a focus more on good answerers than askers - *but the end goal of all this is to create a searchable repository of knowledge*.

---

## Problem

**I tried to lookup some documentation, and it was cumbersome** (and not only because it doesn't show up in Google results). Some major points:

- I have to navigate to the tag
- I have to navigate to the topic, thus know how it is worded
- Alternately, I can use the search inside the tag, which is not really helpful because

  - It only returns examples
  - The order of examples seems terrible to say the least
  - Suggestions dropping down from the search box can be useful but are slow to show/update

**Take this really simple example**: I want to know how to commit with Git, simply and quickly, rather than [having to read all of this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit). Here's my Docs.SO experience:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation
2. Type "git", click Git in the filtered boxes
3. Glance at first five topics (because I can't be asked to scroll); nothing on commits
4. Type "commit" in search box
5. Wait a second, still only "Popular" topics in dropdown list
6. Press enter and go to [this horrible page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=git&query=commit) where I don't know what link to choose and most of them seem unrelated (for that specific issue, see [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329534/documentations-search-algorithm-should-be-more-intelligent) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329828/issues-with-searches-in-documentation)).
7. Abandon and turn to Google

That's obviously a poor experience.

---

## Suggestions

Here's a two pretty concrete ideas to improve the state of the search.

1. **Make search page show topics.** Whether it is mixed with examples or separate doesn't matter. Just show the topics that already appear in the drop-down menu, in case I missed them.

   Rationale: I think the goal of having topics with examples pinned and ordered per votes is to get a nice, sightly presentation where one can choose the specific interesting example. We should direct readers there, and let them look at examples from that page.

   Plus, topics are much easier to get right from a simple query.
2. **Give us a search box where you can use "[tag] query"** that redirects to `https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag={tag}&query={query}`

   This is similar to the Q&A search and would cut out most of the steps described above. Optionally offer helpful message of similarly named tags if misspelt/doesn't exist/etc.

   Maybe next to the "Type to find a tag: " box, we could have a "Search documentation: " with "[tag] query" as background text.

Comment: "*That's obviously a poor experience.*" It fits right in with the experience of searching in Q&A. Stack Exchange seems to hate implementing decent search systems.

Comment: *"and not only because it doesn't show up in google results"*. It takes time for pages to be indexed into Google.

Comment: @theblindprophet [not for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98083/how-does-stackoverflow-get-indexed-by-google-in-such-as-fast-manner)

Comment: @theblindprophet BTW - The documentation pages are currently not indexed by Google (`<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />`) so you won't find it on google

Comment: The documentation search engine is not usable as it is - I tried searching "Overload" in the C++ documentation, here are [the results](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=c%2B%2B&query=overload). On the first page with ~15 results, only 3 are **directly** related to overload, the others mostly contains the term "overload" in their content, and I am not even talking about the order - Yes, the topic "Overload resolution" (search term in the title, 5 score, 8 examples, most of them containing the term "overload" multiple times) is at the bottom of the page...